# EF Core/PostgreSQL Column is null exception in Docker

Tags: postgresql, docker, ef-core-7.0

I'm moving a WebApi project (efcore 7) to a Docker container. The new implementation is accessing a PostgreSQL instance in its own container. Things are running fine, but I'm having one exception that I can't resolve.

I have a model declared as follows:

```
public class Member
{
    public Guid MemberId { get; set; }
    public string UserName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string Code { get; set; }
    public int Status { get; set; }
}
```

The field Code causes a problem for EF and PostgreSQL when it contains `null`. When retrieving a Member record with the null value in Code, it returns the error message:

```
System.InvalidCastException: Column 'Code' is null.
at Npgsql.ThrowHelper.ThrowInvalidCastException_NoValue(FieldDescription field)
at Npgsql.NpgsqlDataReader.GetFieldValue[T](Int32 ordinal)
at Npgsql.NpgsqlDataReader.GetString(Int32 ordinal)
...
```

The migration that creates the table declares the Code property as:
`table.Column<string>(type: "text", nullable: true)`, so it *should* be able to contain a null value.

What's more confusing is that this exception occurs ONLY when the WebApi is running in the Docker container. The code runs normally outside of Docker, in either Debug or Release mode.

Does anybody have an idea what is causing this strange behavior?

Answer (score 0):

As it turned out, there was a discrepancy between the two projects. The webapi environment was using the nullable option, and the model (which was in another project) was not. Once I enabled nullable on the model project and implemented it, the error went away.